# VISA api: Fail to post requests with this error, "Expected input credential was not present"

Tags: ssl, post, request, credentials, visa-api

I'm new to VISA developer and trying to send requests to https://sandbox.api.visa.com/cofds-web/v1/datainfo to check whether the credit card is valid or not in Python.

Python code:

```
cert = 'C:\\Users\\user\\visa_cert\\cert.pem'

ca_cert = 'C:\\Users\\user\\visa_cert\\ca_cert.cer'
key = 'C:\\Users\\user\\visa_cert\\my_key.pem'

user_id = 'your user id of your project'
password = 'your password of your project'
timeout = 10

cred_info = 'credit_info.json'

payload = json.loads('''{
  "requestHeader": {
    "requestMessageId": "6da6b8b024532a2e0eacb1af58581",
    "messageDateTime": "2019-02-35 05:25:12.327"
  },
  "requestData": {
    "pANs": [
      4072208010000000
    ],
    "group": "STANDARD"
  }
}
''')

try:
    response = requests.post(url,
                            verify = (ca_cert),
                            cert=(cert, key),
                            # headers = headers,
                            auth=(user_id, password),
                            json = payload,
                            timeout=timeout
    )
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Execution itself succeeded, but the response says the "Ecpectd input credential was not present"

Response header and contetns are as below.

```
# response header:
{'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Fri, 03 Jun 2022 13:52:17 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '130', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'X-SERVED-BY': 'c6795c5t4', 'X-CORRELATION-ID': '1654264337_872_241384137_c6795c5t4_VDP_WS', 'X-ERROR-ORIGIN': '9200', 'X-APP-STATUS': '400', 'X-Frame-Options':
'SAMEORIGIN', 'X-XSS-Protection': '0', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000;includeSubdomains', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expires': '-1'}
 
# response content:
b'{"responseStatus":{"status":400,"code":"9125","severity":"ERROR","message":"Expected input credential was not present","info":""}}'
```

I followed the instruction here(https://developer.visa.com/pages/working-with-visa-apis/two-way-ssl#configuring_a_twoway_ssl_keystor...) to generate the CA certificate, double-checked my user_id and password are correct and two-way SSL certificate is active.

I googled this error, but I'm still not sure how to fix this problem.

Thank you.
passiveradio

Answer (score 0):

So this API requires Message Level Encryption so I have been struggling to figure out how to implement the MLE with the API, if you try to use the Visa Developer Center with MLE enabled you will get the error you're getting but if you run it with MLE enabled it works.

So if you figure out how to implement MLE in the code I would be grateful because the documentation is very vague.

https://developer.visa.com/pages/encryption_guide

Answer (score 0):

This error is not a result of MLE. It's because #keyId is missing from the request header. You can generate a keyid from the dashboard -> project name -> credentials then scroll down to Encryption and Decryption. Click Generate keyId.

After getting the key, you must add a "keyId" header with a value of the generated key. Now send the request.

After the request is sent, this is where visa attempts to validate MLE with the keyId. you must now get an error like "Token validation failed"

Comment: How to solve the "Token validation failed" error?